# I want to put something including > into a .txt file (batch)

Tags: batch-file, text

i have a little problem , I want to put "dir > "c:\users\myname\desktop\a.txt""
into a Txtdokument. But if I run the code it just crahses.

```
    @echo off 
    set va=dir > "c:\users\myname\desktop\a.txt"
    echo. %va% > txt.txt
    pause
```

i have no idea what i did wrong.

Comment: Why not just `echo dir ^> "c:\users\myname\desktop\a.txt" > txt.txt`? Why you use a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and follow the [*Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes*](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) article. Explained using `REM` comments:

```
@echo off 
REM ↓                                         ↓ all in double quotes is taken literally
set "va=dir ^> "c:\users\myname\desktop\a.txt""
REM         ↑                                   the caret escapes > used in following echo
echo.%va%> txt.txt
pause
```

Comment: What if i want to Put %ho% into the Dokument but i dont want it turns in the variable?

Comment: _if i want to Put `%ho%` into the Dokument_: `echo.%%ho%%>>txt.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's an alternative utilising delayed expansion.

```bat
@Echo Off 
Set "va=dir > "c:\users\myname\desktop\a.txt""
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo(!va!)>txt.txt
EndLocal
```